# Solr DIH XML do not extracting

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm trying to index some wiki pages using Solr 7.0, but in the last step for that, the DataImportHandler apparently isn't extracting the data. I don't know what is happening, because no error is being thrown.

When I call http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/dataimport?command=full-import two different behaviors are noticeable.

The first response for my first request is.

```
{
    "responseHeader":{
        "status":0,
        "QTime":75
    },
    "initArgs":[
        "defaults",[
            "config","data-config.xml"
         ]
     ],
    "command":"full-import",
    "status":"idle",
    "importResponse":"",
    "statusMessages":{}
 }
```

The second response when I just press enter again is.

```
{
    "responseHeader":{
        "status":0,
        "QTime":26
    },
    "initArgs":[
        "defaults",[
            "config","data-config.xml"
        ]
    ],
    "command":"full-import",
    "status":"idle",
    "importResponse":"",
    "statusMessages":{
        "Total Requests made to DataSource":"0",
        "Total Rows Fetched":"2",
        "Total Documents Processed":"0",
        "Total Documents Skipped":"0",
        "Full Dump Started":"2017-10-28 07:05:31",
        "":"Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 
            documents.",
        "Committed":"2017-10-28 07:05:31",
        "Time taken":"0:0:0.449"
    }
}
```

As you can see in the second answer, the DIH found 2 documents. It's exactly the number of the document that I have in my test file `wiki.xml`. The problem is DIH isn't extracting as you may notice in `Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.`

Here is my Solr configuration: [git gist](https://gist.github.com/JEricFarias/b758023d020323caf19c27f01aa39a46). I'm using Windows 10, Solr 7.0 and Lucene 7.0.

What I've tried so far...

- One those data that I'm trying to extract is the "user", but there are some irregularities with it, for example, the `<contributor>` XML tag have some time two subtag `<username>`(the user nickname) and `<id>`(the user id) when a user has an account and some other times when the user doesn't have an account the `<contributor>` appears only with one subtag `<ip>`. So I just try to import the data without the "user" data.
- I'm just trying to get only the id and title. To that, I comment the other fields in `data-config.xml`.

No one those tests work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is very simple, your `entity` tag is closed initially, so all following `fields` tags are ignored.

So, you need to add `</entity>` tag afterwards and replace `<entity/>` with just `<entity>`

However, your solrconfig.xml still contains a mistake, you're using `ClassicIndexSchemaFactory`, but you have `AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory`, which will cause an exception. You should rather replace classic schema factory with managed one, or just remove this add fields update processor factory.